# bootstrap data-target requirements/dependencies/debugging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on an existing Bootstrap solution in my workplace.  It has the following markup:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

I'm somewhat new to Bootstrap but I did some basic googling.  data-target is used to specify a child modal window to open.  Markup similar to the markup above successfully opens a new modal window in a different enterprise website.

What are the requirements/dependencies for this implementation to work? For example, which supporting files are necessary? I'm assuming that should handle this this natively as opposed to requiring a jQuery click event wireup.

Can you please confirm if this is the case?  I'm new to Bootstrap but this will help me focus  my debugging.  If the code above isn't working then what would you investigate as most likely root causes?

Comment: `bootstrap.js` .. which requires `jquery.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `jquery.js` is required by bootstrap as well as a few others.

I believe this link may be helpful for your question as well:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target